# UILabel Not Working with Tableview in XCode 6 Beta

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, xcode6

Not sure if this is just a beta issue, or if XCode made a change between 5 and 6 that I'm not seeing.

I have an app that segues through a series of tableviews. For most of the tableviews, the text in the cells are simply supplied by the data in the arrays that are fed into them. But for one of my tables, I needed to format the text, and thus needed to add a Label to the cell, so I could do some formatting.

This all works fine in XCode 5, but in 6 the tableview with the label appears with a blank gray screen. No tableview, no list. Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"formCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *formLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    formLabel.text = [self.formDistinct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I posted in Swift and you asked in Obj-C.. Sorry!

I am running into the same issue. I found if I programmatically added the UILabel it worked fine. As a courtesy I will post some code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {

    var cell:ThemeCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("themeCell") as ThemeCell

    cell.themeName.text = arrayOfCustomStringsOrSomething[indexPath.row].capitalizedString // Must be consistent! ;)

    return cell
}
```

and then your custom cell class named ThemeCell:

```
class ThemeCell: UITableViewCell {

var themeName: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 40))

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addSubview(themeName)
}
```

}